# How to open xls file with macros inside using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

The problem is that I can't open workbook from `inputstream` with xls file.
When I trying open it by `WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: Not enough data (0) to read requested (1) bytes
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.checkRecordPosition(RecordInputStream.java:216)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.readByte(RecordInputStream.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.readUByte(RecordInputStream.java:260)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.DConRefRecord.<init>(DConRefRecord.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory$ReflectionConstructorRecordCreator.create(RecordFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createSingleRecord(RecordFactory.java:338)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.readNextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:310)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:276)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:480)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:326)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:172)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:143)
    at ru.efo.search.support.excel.WorkBookReader.init(WorkBookReader.java:67)
    at ru.efo.search.support.excel.WorkBookReader.<init>(WorkBookReader.java:42)
    at ru.efo.search.support.excel.WorkBookReader.main(WorkBookReader.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

But if the same file is .xlsm format it works ok, because `WorkbookFactory` uses `XSSFWorkbook` instead of `HSSFWorkbook`. Unfortunately, I have only `InputStream` in my application and I can't change file format. Please, help!

Comment: If you open the `.xls` file in Excel, and do a Save-As, does the new file get read ok? And have you made sure you're on the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Files I have only for test. In app I have only InputStream. I've tried with 3.12 and 3.13 version, both didn't work.

Comment: But does it work with a file when testing? And if not, does it work if you load the file in Excel, do a save-as, and load that?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I use file or IS. Both don't work. When I save xls in .xlsm it starts work. Saving xls as xls doesn't help. But the point is that I need open xls file =(